# Changing xkey morris line chart to string

Tags: javascript, charts, line, morris.js

How can I change the value from `xkey` to use a text value and not a numeric value?

I have tried changing it to "iPhone", but it did not work.

```js
var line = new Morris.Line({
    element: 'line-chart',
    resize: true,
            data: [
                   {y: '2011 Q1', item1: 2666},
                   {y: '2011 Q2', item1: 2778},
                   {y: '2011 Q3', item1: 4912},
                   {y: '2011 Q4', item1: 3767},
                   {y: '2012 Q1', item1: 6810},
                   {y: '2012 Q2', item1: 5670},
                   {y: '2012 Q2', item1: 5670},
                   {y: '2012 Q2', item1: 5670},
                  ],
    xkey: 'y',
    ykeys: ['item1'],
    labels: ['Item 1'],
    lineColors: ['#3c8dbc'],
    hideHover: 'auto'
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand what you want to do. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Add the property: parseTime:false.

Your code changed:

```
var line = new Morris.Line({
    element: 'line-chart',
    resize: true,
            data: [
                   {y: '2011 Q1', item1: 2666},
                   {y: '2011 Q2', item1: 2778},
                   {y: '2011 Q3', item1: 4912},
                   {y: '2011 Q4', item1: 3767},
                   {y: '2012 Q1', item1: 6810},
                   {y: '2012 Q2', item1: 5670},
                   {y: '2012 Q2', item1: 5670},
                   {y: '2012 Q2', item1: 5670},
                  ],
    xkey: 'y',
    ykeys: ['item1'],
    labels: ['Item 1'],
    lineColors: ['#3c8dbc'],
    parseTime:false,
    hideHover: 'auto'
});
```